# Using array functions with a serialized array in ActiveRecord Ruby

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I've got a serialized array

```
class Enviroment < ActiveRecord::Base
serialize :roles, Array

...
t.column :roles, :string, :default=> Array.new
```

and I would like do things like

```
Enviroment.find(1).roles.push 'thing'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing such default value will save it's YAML representation as String into the Database and Rails unserializes that back into string. That's why it is not working.

Also, maybe you'd want to use `text` as the column type, so that your array won't be truncated when it gets longer. In recent Rails syntax, that would be:

```
t.text :roles
```

And when you want to store new role into database, you'd have to save the object afterwards (in contrast to `has_many` association which is automatically saved b/c it's key is in the *other* table):

```
e = Environment.find(1)
e.roles.push 'thing'
e.save
```

Or if it absolutely needs to be oneliner:

```
Environment.find(1).tap{|e| e.roles.push 'things'}.save
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! not sure what's the meaning of text there, but it worked. I guess all the serialized objects should have ':text' type??

Comment: Yes. Though I doubt there are any actual restrictions. Only that based on the length of your serialized output, it could get truncated if it won't fit in `string` type (dependent on database probably).